# convert string[] to int?[]

Tags: c#

how to convert a string array to nullable integer array.

Answer (score 10):

Well, the two aspects are:

- How do you convert an array from one type to another?
- How do you convert a string to a nullable int?

The first is simple - you can use [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx), passing in an `Converter` delegate. There's the LINQ way as well (`x.Select(...).ToArray()`), but that's slightly less efficient if you know you've got an array to start with and you want an array out of the other end <sup>1</sup>.

The `string` to `int?` is probably best done in a method. You can do it in an anonymous function, but in this particular case I'd use a separate method. I rarely like to have to declare variables in an anonymous function.

```
public static int? TryParseInt32(string text)
{
    int value;
    return int.TryParse(text, out value) ? value : (int?) null;
}
```

To answer the comment, yes you need the cast <sup>2</sup>.

or without the conditional:

```
public static int? TryParseInt32(string text)
{
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(text, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Put them together like this:

```
string[] x = {"15", "10", "hello", "5" };        
int?[] y = Array.ConvertAll(x, TryParseInt32);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `Array.ConvertAll` is more efficient than `x.Select().ToArray()` because it has more information. It can create the final array *immediately* - no resizing is ever required. Calling `Enumerable.ToArray()` (with the result of `Select()`) doesn't have the same information, so it effectively has to add the results to a `List<T>` (potentially resizing several times along the way) and then usually resize at the end as well. (It doesn't actually use `List<T>` but the concepts are the same.) It's definitely worth knowing about the Select/ToArray solution, but I don't think it's actually any more readable than `ConvertAll` in this case, so you might as well use the more efficient form.

<sup>2</sup> The reason you need the cast in the conditional is because the compiler doesn't know what type of "null" you really mean - but it knows it can't convert from `null` to an `int`. The type of the conditional expression has to be *either* the type of the second operand *or* the type of the third operand, and the other one has to be implicitly convertibly. By forcing the third operand to be of type `int?` here everything is fine - because you can implicitly convert from `int` to `int?`. Note that the compiler *doesn't* take the way you're using the expression to try to work out the type. Another alternative is to use `new int?()` instead of `null`.

Comment: I think you mixed up the result values in your conditional expression.

Comment: Should I have to cast null to (int?) ?

Comment: @Ahmed: yes, the cast is necessary in the first case.

Comment: @Konrad: Yeah, I spotted the mistake but my laptop connect is The Suck right now :(

Comment: Is `(int?) null` more efficient than `new int?()`?

Comment: @cdmckay: They're exactly equivalent. They'll compile to the same code.

Answer (score 5):

By parsing and using Linq:

```
string[] input = { "1", "3", "x" }
var result = input.Select(
    s => { int i; return (int.TryParse(s, out i)) ? i : (int?) null; }).ToArray();
```

… but I grant that this is a bit cryptic. I wouldn’t use a lambda expression here. For clarity, this should belong to a proper function `ParseNullableInt`. Then you can call it like this:

```
var result = input.Select(ParseNullableInt).ToArray();
```

Comment: No need for LINQ - use `Array.ConvertAll` for improved performance, plus you can use it all the way back to .NET 2.

Comment: @280Z28: Improved performance – really? Seems unlikely. Furthermore, I believe that these old functions are somewhat superseded by the `Enumerable` extension functions. Consistency, and all that. True about .NET 2.0 though.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes, improved performance. Consider the information that ToArray has after a call to Select: not a lot. In particular, it *doesn't* know how big to make the array to start with... so it'll start with a small array, then when that runs out of space it'll create a new array, copy over all the existing values etc - and then trim at the end. Compare that with Array.ConvertAll - it knows exactly how big to make the array to start with. Try it with a large array and a trivial conversion and you'll definitely see a difference.

Comment: @Jon: oops, completely forgot about `ToArray` because I rarely use it. Right of course.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: I removed the null/empty check because [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) properly handles those cases by returning false.

```
string[] stringArray = ...;
int?[] nullableIntArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray,
    s =>
    {
        int value;
        if (!int.TryParse(s, out value))
            return default(int?);
        return (int?)value;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be this (I'm presuming that you want nulls for the values that were not integer values):

```
public static class StringArrayExtension
{
    public static int?[] ToNullableIntArray(this string[] array)
    {
        int?[] result = new int?[array.Length];
        for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
        {
            string sourceValue = array[index];
            int destinationValue;
            if (int.TryParse(sourceValue, out destinationValue))
            {
                result[index] = destinationValue;
            }
            else
            {
                result[index] = null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string[] source = { "hello", "1", "3.1415", "20", "foo" };
int?[] dest = source.ToNullableIntArray();
```

Comment: Why create a `List<T>` when you know you want an array at the end, and you know exactly how big it should be?

Comment: Again, this is exactly what `Array.ConvertAll` is for. Stop reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use int.TryParse:

```
    string[] s = { "123", "a", "45" };
    int?[] result = new int?[s.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
    {
        int a;
        if (int.TryParse(s[i], out a))
            result[i] = a;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int?> ints = new List<int?>();
foreach (string str in strs)
{
    int val;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out val))
    {
        ints.Add(val);
    }
    else { ints.Add(null); }
}
return ints.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -2):

An integer array can not be null. In fact every element in Integer Array will have "0" by default.

Regarding Conversion

Create an Integer array of the same length or an arraylist

```
int [] _arr=new int[strArray.length];
for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++]
{
   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strArray[i]))
   {
       _arr[i]=0;
   }
   else
   {
       _arr[i]=int.Parse(strArray[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: An integer array can't have a null, but an nullable integer array can ;)   `int?[] nullableInts` FTW